# Is it possible to override key press functionality in python?

Tags: python

I'm writing a stenography like script, such that, when you press specific combination of keys on your keyboard such as "ASDF" it would translate to a word and type out the word instead of your key presses. However I cannot find a way to override key presses such that programs such as Notepad will ignore me typing "ASDF".

My only current solution to this has been to have my script backspace the characters that were typed, then paste the word that was intended to be typed.

Here is my script thus far:

```py
import ctypes

def main():
    GetAsyncKeyState = ctypes.windll.user32.GetAsyncKeyState
    key_states = [0] * 26
    pressed_keys = [0] * 26
    chord = ''
    while True:
        for k in range(65,91):
            key_states[k-65] = GetAsyncKeyState(k)
            if GetAsyncKeyState(k): pressed_keys[k-65] = 1
        if sum(key_states) == 0:
            for k in range(26):
                if pressed_keys[k] == 1:
                    chord += chr(k+65)
            if chord != '': write(chord)
            chord = ''
            pressed_keys = [0] * 26

dictionary = open('dictionary.txt','r').read()
entries = dictionary.split('\n')
chords = [[0,0]]*len(entries)
for e in range(len(entries)):
    s = entries[e].split('-')
    chords[e] = [s[0],s[1]]

def write(chord):
    found = 0
    for c in chords:
        if chord==c[0]:
            found = 1
            _type(c[1])
    if not found:
        _type(chord)

def _type(word):
    '''
    This is where the code would go...
    '''

main()
```

The expected results would be that none of the characters I'm typing would show up until the script pastes the final word. But instead, my characters that I'm pressing to form the word show up first.

My plan would be to override the keys to do nothing.
I.E. when I pressed "e" nothing would occur.

Comment: Judging for your code, you want this to work on Windows, right?

Comment: Yes, my goal is to essentially redirect my keyboard input to my program, and have other programs ignore keyboard input, all on windows.

Comment: Check out the `keyboard` module.

Comment: Have you read the doc of [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html)?